# Is it possible to verify a saved SSL session against public key of server

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I am working on an app where people will be able to track prices of products.
- I want their phones be able to crawl some of the sites where this product appears (with their consent), twice a day.
- I don't want to redundantly do this, if two users are watching the product, I want to only use one of them to do the crawling.
- Once crawling a product is complete, the crawling result will be pushed to server (to prevent redundant crawling).
- In the last step, the data is pushed from an "untrusted" source. Someone can reverse engineer the network traffic and potentially push garbage to the end point. I want the crawled "HTML" be authentic, and coming from the merchant site it is intended to.

Here is the question:
- I was thinking it may be achieved by storing encrypted SSL traffic for a particular request, and on the server side, I could validate the it against the public key of the merchant certificate (let's say, newegg).

However, I am not entirely sure if this is going to work, and i am stuck with coding it. Code snippets for would be appreciated (as long as it's not straight out of openssl commands :))

Comment: no, because TLSv1.3 provides [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). see also [Does a trace of SSL packets provide a proof of data authenticity?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/does-a-trace-of-ssl-packets-provide-a-proof-of-data-authenticity) and [Is it possible to store / record HTTPS client auth traffic as a signed document?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/231014/is-it-possible-to-store-record-https-client-auth-traffic-as-a-signed-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should in theory be possible to verify a captured TLS handshake against the servers certificate (i.e. public key inside the certificate) in order to be sure that this handshake was created with the server. But, this alone is no proof that the decrypted data and the TLS handshake belong to the same TLS session. For this you would also need the (pre-)master secret of the connection.

Note that modifying the bot that it will extract the (pre-)master secret from the internal SSL state and the encrypted traffic, store this secret and the encrypted traffic together with the plain traffic and write some code to verify that all this belongs together is not a trivial task. Depending on the SSL library used it might be necessary to dig deep into the internals and use undocumented (non-API) functions to do this or grab the information directly from some internal structures.

> Code snippets for would be appreciated (as long as it's not straight out of openssl commands :))

Latest version of OpenSSL have a [SSL_SESSION_get_master_key](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_SESSION_get_master_key.html) function. But I'm not aware of any API in OpenSSL which can be used to verify and decrypt a sniffed session. You might have a look at the source code of Wireshark for this.

If you can trust the bot itself then it will be much simpler to just let the bot sign the decrypted traffic so that you can detect bogus data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. While the crawler is going to be an app  i wrote, and i can implement a basic signing of data, it's futile because the keys would be part of the client mobile app, which means it is easily reverse-engineerablw.

My main worry is the crawled pages will be presented to user and will be used as part of some flow that will require human review. I am worried that someone can abuse, and inject, say, porn, to a page. Otherwise, i can verify certain data sent by client.

Comment: In the meantime, I thought of a very interesting approach - tunneling. When client makes a request to server over websocket, server starts tunneling a TCP/SSL connection to the intended destination over this websocket. After this point, server can simply assert on a whitelisted fingerprint for the certificate.